# Java Web scraping for yahoo finance, extracting analyst rating

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to get the analyst rating of a given stock from yahoo finance using Java.
I am using jsoup but looks like when I print the main HTML I am unable to see output which I see in the browser console. Is there anything I am missing. Yahoo finance is full of JavaScript. So I don't see the script information in jsoup object.

Thanks bilal

Comment: JavaScript and JSoup don't work well together.

Comment: Thanks... Is there better way of handling besides jsoup.

Comment: Either inspect the javascript requests and try to query data using their API calls or use a headless browser with javascript support: HtmlUnit is an option for java, though it is not the fastest or most stable lib. Alternatively use something like PhantomJS to grab the rendered page, write the output to a file and parse with jsoup (this is faster than HtmlUnit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check all the requests being shown in your browser's network tab. One of them would have the data set you require, most probably in JSON.